# Toggle display of div when targeting icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have three icon images in the header. They consist of a camera, a bike, and a baby. I wante to hide/display corresponding images in the body depending on which icon is clicked.  The previous image should hide as the next icon is clicked. I would also like the default on page load to be "hidden".

I also want to be able to click the icon once to show the image and again, to re-hide.

**CSS**

```
img {
    margin: 15px;
}
.camera {
    display: none;
}
.bike {
    display: none;
}
.baby {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var _hidediv = null;

function showdiv(id) {
    if (_hidediv) _hidediv();
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    _hidediv = function () {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="showdiv('camera');"> 
    <img src="camera.png" />
</a>
<a onclick="showdiv('bike');">
    <img src="bike.png" />
    <a onclick="showdiv('baby');">
        <img src="baby.png" />

        <div id="camera" style="display: none;"> 
            <img src="camera1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="bike" style="display: none;"> 
            <img src="bike1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="baby" style="display: none;">
            <img src="baby1.jpg" />
        </div>
```

Comment: First thing you need to learn is how to create a jsFiddle so others can help you with your code. You'll find it of great personal use, as well. Here is your code cleaned up and placed into a [<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/T8eGS/)

Comment: Yes, you're missing some closing </a> tags in your header.

Comment: Just for clarification: there's no `jsFiddle` key on any keyboard :)

Comment: take your script out of your style.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. Yeah, my code is sloppy. Novice is even a stretch for what I am but I'm working on it. I'll also use jsFiddle from now on. Cheers.

Comment: @abc123 That was my big problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ZTkLg/2/)

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="showdiv('camera');"> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</a>
<a onclick="showdiv('bike');">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" />
</a>
<a onclick="showdiv('baby');">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300" />
</a>    


<div id="camera" style="display: none;"> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div id="bike" style="display: none;"> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" />
</div>
<div id="baby" style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var _hidediv = null;
var previousDiv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(_hidediv != null){
      _hidediv();
    }

    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if(div != previousDiv)
    {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        _hidediv = function() { div.style.display = 'none'; };
        previousDiv = div;
    }
    else
    {
        previousDiv = null;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  margin: 15px;
}
.camera {
  display: none;
}
.bike {
  display: none;
}
.baby {
  display: none;
}
```

***Description***

*This seems to satisfy all your needs.*

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling this is what I finally came up with. Works for a good image toggle.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hidden { display: none; }
  .unhidden { display: inline; }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    .unhidden {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divID);
        if (item) {
            item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:unhide('camera');"> 
          <img src="img/camera.png" /></a>
 <a href="javascript:unhide('bike');">  
          <img src="img/bike.png" /></a>
 <a href="javascript:unhide('baby');"> 
          <img src="img/baby.png" /></a>

<div id="camera" class="hidden">
    <img src="img/camera1.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="bike" class="hidden">
    <img src="img/bike1.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="baby" class="hidden">
    <img src="img/baby1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach a hide show event on the click of the anchor tag. I have used jQuery to solve the problem. What I did was that I bound the click event of the anchor tag and picked up the href of the tag which is potentially the id of the div element. Then you can just hide and show the div

```
$('img').click(function () {
    var divId = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
    $('div:not(' + divId + ')').hide();
    $(divId).show();
});
```

You can find the complete jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hHrU/)